# What does the poclbm output mean?

Tags: terminology, poclbm

I have 3 graphics cards mining with poclbm (no external pool) and they all have pretty much the same output:

```
MYSERVER:MYPORT [141.642 MH/s (~0 MH/s)] [Rej: 0/0 (0.00%)]
```

what does the "~0 MH/s" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [poclbm source code](https://github.com/m0mchil/poclbm), Switch.py [line 219](https://github.com/m0mchil/poclbm/blob/master/Switch.py#L219):

```
say_quiet('%s[%.03f MH/s (~%d MH/s)] [Rej: %d/%d (%.02f%%)]', (if_else(verbose, miner.id()+' ', '') , rate, round(estimated_rate), rejected_shares, total_shares, float(rejected_shares) * 100 / total_shares_estimator))
```

It's `estimated_rate`.

And how `estimated_rate` that found, you ask?
I tried looking at the source, but that didn't really clear things up.

```
self.estimated_rate = Decimal(new_accept) * (targetQ) / min(int(now - self.start_time), self.options.estimate) / 1000
self.estimated_rate = Decimal(self.estimated_rate) / 1000
```

I eventually found [this discussion on bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=34190.0). It states that the estimated rate is based on how many shares are submitted to the pool. I don't know what it's supposed to display if you're not using a pool.